# Python pre order recursive binary tree traversal

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have this code:

```py
def recursionTravel(node, returnArr = []):
    if node:
        returnArr.append(node.data)
        if node.left: returnArr.append(recursionTravel(node.left, returnArr))
        if node.right: returnArr.append(recursionTravel(node.right, returnArr))
    return node.data

# Pre-order traversal
def pre_order(node):
    output = []
    if node:
        output.append(node.data)
        if node.left: output.append(recursionTravel(node.left))
        if node.right: output.append(recursionTravel(node.right))
    return output
```

Binary tree consists of Node: `[5, 10, 2, 'leaf']`
Output should be the same: `[5, 10, 2, 'leaf']`

Issue: Last element is missing in the return. Return value: `[5, 10, 2]`

Comment: It's not possible for this code to return a list with more than three elements, no matter how many nodes are in the tree: that's the number of `output.append()` lines in the main function.  None of the appending you're doing inside `recursionTravel()` becomes part of the output - and it's producing faulty data anyway, due to the "mutable default argument" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the last line of recusiveTravel.

```
def RecusiveTravel(node, returnArr[]):
  if node:
    returnArr.append(node.data)
    if node.left: returnArr.append(recursionTravel(node.left, returnArr))
    if node.right: returnArr.append(recursionTravel(node.right, returnArr))
    return returnArr
```

No need for the preOrder function. Just call it from the recusive function. It should work.